# HDL Generating Comparison between Matlab HDL Coder and Xilinx Vitis HLS

Tags: matlab, simulation, fpga, xilinx, hdl

We're considering the approach on a new project. Our target is developing image processing algorithms and implement them on FPGAs.

Matlab HDL Coder converts matlab code to HDL code, and Xilinx Vitis HLS synthesizes C/C++/SystemC to HDL code.

We can make a quick judgment that algorithm development using Matlab is much less painful than lower level programming languages such as C/C++/SystemC.

Is there any things else about these tools which we should know?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Vitis HLS pro

Vitis HLS can provide:

- A packaged IP already for you with no further modifications
- The generated code might use primitives and structures to facilitate the synthetizer when generating the netlist.
- AXI interfaces (Stream, Lite, Full) ready for integration in your block design.
- Nice RTL/C cosimulation to detect early bugs.

So **if you are targeting Xilinx devices** I would suggest C++ HLS with Vitis.

#### HLS challenges

Be aware that HLS is quite difficult to master, and that's because the procedural nature of C++ is fundamentally different from HDLs. This makes generation of conditional branches not clear. Be wary of using too many branches in your code.

Try to keep a "dataflow" style in mind, where data is streamed in and an output is produced in a clear, pipelined, streamed fashion.

Be wary also of memory accesses and latency throughout your system, sometimes the bottlenecks aren't where you think they are.

#### Alternatives

Lastly, a suggestion about using HLS at all. There are many libraries in FPGA already done (for instance [here](https://github.com/Xilinx/PYNQ-ComputerVision)) that use native FPGA HDL but provide you accelerators for the basic blocks of **computer vision** to use within your software. You might just want to use them without need to reinvent the wheel.

I hope it helps!